# Load data from XML nodes

Tags: c#, xml

i have this structure of data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1250"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="usb71105.xsl"?>
<manas:usb xmlns:manas="http://www.manas.info/">
  <manas:qr00>
    <manas:verzemanas>26052708</manas:verzemanas>
    <manas:verzexml>2016.03.29a</manas:verzexml>
    <manas:druhtisku>U_Tisk2P/2159405/TRUE</manas:druhtisku>
  </manas:qr00>
  <manas:qr00>
    <manas:verzemanas>26052710</manas:verzemanas>
    <manas:verzexml>2016.03.30a</manas:verzexml>
    <manas:druhtisku>U_Tisk2P/FALSE</manas:druhtisku>
  </manas:qr00>
</manas:usb>
```

I need to save values of: manas:verzemanas ; manas:verzexml ;

I have this code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("d:\\83116623.XML");
foreach (XmlNode node in doc.DocumentElement)
{
   string name = node.Attributes[0].ToString();
}
```

Have you any ideas please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably better off with `XDocument`. Also you need to use the `namespace` prefix. E.g.:

```
    XNamespace ns = "http://www.manas.info/";
    var xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\temp\a\a.xml");
    var verze = xdoc.Root.Elements(ns + "qr00")
                         .Elements(ns + "verzemanas")
                         .Select(e => e.Value);

    verze.ToList().ForEach(v => Console.WriteLine(v));
```

prints

```
26052708
26052710
```